# How to restore form values from $form_state['values']?

Tags: 7, forms, database

I save the `$form_sate['values']` in a data base. When my users come back to the form I want to show the values that they put before. Something like:

```
function my_form($form, &$form_sate) {
  $form_state_saved = get_form_state_values_from_db();

  $form['my_field'] = array(
    ...
    '#default_value' = $form_state_saved['my_field'];
    ...
  );

  return $form;
}
```

With a `textfield` seems that works fine, but I have some custom fields. Is there a way to set the `default_value` from *db*? Or should I implement the `default_value` independently for each field?

Comment: I think you've answered yourself the question. Every element in your form could be filled with the default value.

Comment: You should implement `default_value` independently for each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what my colleague did was a combination of [`field_default_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.form.inc/function/field_default_form/7) and [`field_form_set_state`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.form.inc/function/field_form_set_state/7).

```
$field_state = array(
  'field' => $field,
  'instance' => $instance,
  'items_count' => $count,
  'array_parents' => array(),
  'errors' => array(),
);
field_form_set_state($parents, $field_name, $language, $form_state, $field_state);
```

`$items` is an array with the form values stored in a database.

```
$form_field = field_default_form('node', NULL, $field, $instance, $language, $items, $form, $form_state);

$form[$field_name] = $form_field[$field_name];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Form default value:

```
'#default_value' => variable_get('sitename_textfield', ''),
```

If you use system_settings_form() you don't need to manually save your variables using a custom form submit function. Note: The variable must have the same name as the form item.

Function details: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7

```
/**
 * Creates/returns a form to configure the variables.
 *
 * @param array $form
 * @param array $form_state
 * @return array
 */
function sitename_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['sitename_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Custom Textfield'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('sitename_textfield', ''),
  );

  // Use system_settings_form() to automate saving configuration variables.
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use variable_set() if you only want to set the previous value 
There is no harm in storing independent values for each fiels element using variable_set()**

```
  function my_form($form, &$form_sate) {
      $form['my_field'] = array(
        ...
        '#default_value' = variable_get('my_field','');
        ...
      );

  return $form;
}
function my_form_submit($form, &$form_sate) {

      variable_set('my_field',  $form['my_field']['#default_value']);




}
```